Not praying fajr salah for many days makes kafir
We know abandoning salah completly is kufr but what about not praying fajr salah for many days, does this makes a person kafir,and praying remaining prayers
Example:- praying fajr once in month
And prays others salah.
Plz don't delete this question iam dealing with waswas
